# Finding the Median given the index of three elements

Tags: java, algorithm

As part of my QuickSort algorithm, I am trying to find the Median value from an Arraylist given the index of the first, middle and last elements. I used several if/else statements as a way of finding it, but it isn't right and the logic is rather convoluted.

Note: Sorting the array is not an option.

```
public static int findMedian(ArrayList <Integer> A, int first, int mid, int last) {
    if(first == mid || first == last || last == mid) {
        return first;
    }
    if(A.get(first) >= A.get(last)) {
        if(A.get(first) <= A.get(mid)) {
            return first;
        }
        else if(A.get(last) >= A.get(mid)) {
            return last;
        }
        return mid;
    }
    else {
        if(A.get(first) > A.get(mid)) {
            return first;
        }
        else if(A.get(mid) > A.get(last)) {
            return last;
        }
        return mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found some methods of solving the occasion where the three values are all different. However, I have to take that into account as the arrays that I generated have random values.

Answer (score 1):

What about this method?

```
public static int findMedian(ArarayList<Integer> A, int first, int mid, int \last) {
    if (first == mid || first == last || last == mid)
        return first;

    int v = (A.get(first) >= A.get(mid)  ? 1 : 0) +
            (A.get(first) >= A.get(last) ? 2 : 0) +
            (A.get(mid)   >= A.get(last) ? 4 : 0);

    switch (v) {
    case 0: /* a < b && a < c && b < c */
        return mid;
    case 1: /* a >= b && a < c && b < c */
        return first;
    case 2: /* a < b && a >= c && b < c -> not possible */
        return -1;
    case 3: /* a >= b && a >= c && b < c */
        return last;
    case 4: /* a < b && a < c && b >= c */
        return last;
    case 5: /* a >= b && a < c && b >= c -> not possible */
        return -1;
    case 6: /* a < b && a >= c && b >= c */
        return first;
    case 7: /* a >= b && a >= c && b >= c */
        return mid;
    }

    /* won't come here */
    return first;
}
```

Or in a more compact form.

```
public static int findMedian(ArarayList<Integer> A, int first, int mid, int \last) {    
    if (first == mid || first == last || last == mid)
        return first;

    int result[] = new int[] { mid, first, -1, last, last, -1, first, mid };

    int v = (A.get(first) >= A.get(mid)  ? 1 : 0) +
            (A.get(first) >= A.get(last) ? 2 : 0) +
            (A.get(mid)   >= A.get(last) ? 4 : 0);

    return result[v];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that looks odd is that if last==mid you return first.

Perhaps it will work better if you simply delete the lines:

```
    if(first == mid || first == last || last == mid) {
        return first;
    }
```

Comment: Actually taking those lines out breaks the program, but I see your point about returning first if last == mid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use `Arrays.sort` on your indices (I realise you can't use a sort on the list itself)? If so you could just sort the indices by value and then pick the middle one:

```
int findMedian(List<Integer> list, int first, int mid, int last) {
    int[] indices = {first, mid, last};
    Arrays.sort(indices, (i1, i2) -> list.get(i1) - list.get(i2));
    return indices[1];
}
```

If you can't use sort for any reason then you can do your own simple insertion sort:

```
int findMedian(List<Integer> list, int first, int mid, int last) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i: Arrays.asList(first, mid, last) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < indices.size() && list.get(i) > list.get(j))
            j++;
        indices.add(j, i);
    }
    return indices.get(1);
}
```

If you don't want to use either of those then I suggest making your `if` statements completely explicit:

```
if (list.get(first) >= list.get(mid) && list.get(first) <= list.get(last)) {
    return first;
else if (list.get(mid) >= list.get(first) && list.get(mid) <= list.get(last)) {
    return mid;
} else {
    return last;
}
```

Comment: Ok then I'll add an alternative.